# Need To Get Count Of Case Status Is New and Count Of All Case Records

Tags: apex

I have a requirement I want to Count all total case records and  count of Which case status was New

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. The general expectation here is that you've made an attempt to write the code/solve the problem on your own first, and will share that attempt and your research. Questions that don't do that tend to be poorly received (downvotes, votes to close). [Edit] your question to add what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

An Aggregate Result query can help here:

```
SELECT COUNT(Id), Status
FROM Case
GROUP BY ROLLUP (Status)
```

This will give you the count of each status, and a final row that includes a grand total of counts.

Comment: Tq ..But i Need without rollup and Count().

Comment: @SureshKumarSurineni We can't see your screen or read your mind, so it's _critically important_ that you be detailed and precise on this site. Using `GROUP BY ROLLUP` and `COUNT()` is probably the easiest, quickest (to implement, perhaps also in execution speed), and most reliable approach here. Please explain _why this solution is not what you're looking for_. Do note that `GROUP BY ROLLUP` is _not the same_ as a rollup summary field. Also, I'll emphasize once more that _you need to show honest effort_. "Thanks, but I need X" makes me feel like you only want someone to do your work for you.